# regex for expression match containing a word but not period

Tags: regex

I am on a quick project cannot learn regex at the moment so need some help. I know its too basic. Please tell me regex that matches expression containing a "becoming_*" but not those containing period. For example

Matchs following expressions:

```
becoming_1
becoming_2
becoming_20
```

But does not match

```
becoming_1.1
becoming_1.5
becoming_2.1
becoming_20.1
becoming_20.50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the lines which has the string  `becoming_` followed by an integer number,

```
^becoming_\d+$
```

OR

```
^becoming_[0-9]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xW6xH3/1)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use it in jquery context? like if I want to select a div
div:[id^=becoming_]

Comment: I cannot use $("div:regex(class, ^becoming_\d+$)") because phpQuery does not support this formt.

Comment: try `^becoming_\\d+$`

Comment: that also doesnot work: pq("div:regex(id, ^becoming_\\d+$)",$html);

Answer (score 0):

You want a string that ends with numbers and not including a period - that's why we are using `\d+` - for numbers, and `$` - that nothing should be after that.

```
/becoming_\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative lookahead with a boundary

```
(becoming_\d+\b(?!\.))
```

You did not tag the question with a specific language, so I am not sure which dialect you are using.